# Powershell Expand Array of results inside pscustomobject

Tags: powershell

Grabbing a bunch of information for DCs across a number of arrays.

Straightforward enough but having issues getting the Fixed Disks objects to return in the desired format:

```
$alldomains = @("domain1.com","domain2.com","domain3.com","domain4.com")
$password = Read-Host "Enter $domain password" -AsSecureString    

Foreach ($domain in $alldomains) {

    $creds = new-object -typename System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -argumentlist "$domain\$env:USERNAME", $password
    $dclist = (Get-ADForest $domain -Credential $creds).Domains | %{(Get-ADDomainController -Filter * -Server $_ ).hostname}
        Foreach ($DC in $dclist) {
            $cpu = gwmi win32_processor -ComputerName $DC -Credential $creds
            $disk = @(gwmi win32_logicaldisk -ComputerName $DC -Credential $creds | ? {$_.drivetype -eq '3'} | select @{N='Drive Letter';E={$_.caption}},description,drivetype,volumename,@{N='Size (GB)';E={[math]::Round(($_.size/1GB),2)}})

            New-Object PSCustomObject -Property @{
                'Domain'=$domain;
                'Hostname'=$DC;
                'CPU Model'=$cpu.name
                'CPU Cores'=$cpu.NumberOfCores
                'CPU Logical Processors'=$cpu.NumberOfLogicalProcessors
                'Memory (GB)'=$memory.Capacity/1GB
                'Fixed Disks'=$($disk)
            }     ormat:
        }
}
```

When I run the script I get the following output:

```
.\tsyDCs.ps1 | ft

CPU Logical Processors Domain                          Hostname                                        CPU Cores CPU Model                                 Memory (GB) Fixed Disks                                                                               
---------------------- ------                          --------                                        --------- ---------                                 ----------- -----------                                                                               
                     4 Domain1.com DC1.Domain1.com         4 Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2680 v3 @ 2.50GHz          16 {@{Drive Letter=C:; description=Local Fixed Disk; drivetype=3; volumename=; Size (GB)=4...
                     4 Domain1.com DC2.Domain1.com         4 Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2680 v3 @ 2.50GHz          16 {@{Drive Letter=C:; description=Local Fixed Disk; drivetype=3; volumename=; Size (GB)=4...
                     4 Domain1.com DC3.Domain1.com         4 Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2680 v3 @ 2.50GHz          16 {@{Drive Letter=C:; description=Local Fixed Disk; drivetype=3; volumename=; Size (GB)=4...
                     4 Domain1.com DC4.Domain1.com         4 Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2680 v3 @ 2.50GHz          16 {@{Drive Letter=C:; description=Local Fixed Disk; drivetype=3; volumename=; Size (GB)=4...
                    12 Domain2.com DC1.Domain2.com         6 Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2620 0 @ 2.00GHz           16 {@{Drive Letter=C:; description=Local Fixed Disk; drivetype=3; volumename=; Size (GB)=1...
                    12 Domain2.com DC2.Domain2.com         6 Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2620 0 @ 2.00GHz           16 {@{Drive Letter=C:; description=Local Fixed Disk; drivetype=3; volumename=; Size (GB)=1...
                    12 Domain2.com DC3.Domain2.com         6 Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2620 0 @ 2.00GHz           16 {@{Drive Letter=C:; description=Local Fixed Disk; drivetype=3; volumename=System; Size ...
                    12 Domain2.com DC4.Domain2.com         6 Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2620 0 @ 2.00GHz           16 {@{Drive Letter=C:; description=Local Fixed Disk; drivetype=3; volumename=; Size (GB)=1...
                     2 Domain3.com  DC1.Domain3.com          2 Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2680 v3 @ 2.50GHz          16 {@{Drive Letter=C:; description=Local Fixed Disk; drivetype=3; volumename=; Size (GB)=9...
                     2 Domain3.com  DC2.Domain3.com          2 Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2680 v3 @ 2.50GHz          16 {@{Drive Letter=C:; description=Local Fixed Disk; drivetype=3; volumename=; Size (GB)=1...
                    12 Domain4.com  DC1.Domain4.com          6 Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2620 0 @ 2.00GHz           16 {@{Drive Letter=C:; description=Local Fixed Disk; drivetype=3; volumename=System; Size ...
                    12 Domain4.com  DC2.Domain4.com          6 Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2620 0 @ 2.00GHz           16 {@{Drive Letter=C:; description=Local Fixed Disk; drivetype=3; volumename=System; Size ...
```

How can I expand those results with the pscustomobject, and is there a way to embed a 'table' inside the | FT results?

Comment: What is "the desired format"? Put some examples in your post of how you want it to be, and either it will help us work out how to get that, or trying to do that by hand will show you how there is no simple answer. "*is there a way to embed a 'table' inside the | FT results?*" - yes. You've done it, your Fixed Disks property is an array of objects, and your output is what nested 'rows' looks like with default formatting.

Comment: Desired results would be the Fixed Disks column showing all information instead of the truncatd output it's displaying at present.

Comment: Presumably it is truncated because there is not enough room to show all the information. If you don't want data missing and you don't want it truncated, then you will need to say what you *do* want to see. Do you need them to be PSCustomObjects still or could they become strings - or a single string? Do you want multiple lines for each disk? Narrower other columns? A wider console screen? A table with headers inside? Have you tried `ft -AutoSize` or `ft -Wrap` or both? What if a server has 5 or 20 disks?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This did it:

```
$alldomains = @("domain1.com","domain2.com","domain3.com","domain4.com")
$password = Read-Host "Enter $domain password" -AsSecureString    

Foreach ($domain in $alldomains) {

    $creds = new-object -typename System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -argumentlist "$domain\$env:USERNAME", $password
    $dclist = (Get-ADForest $domain -Credential $creds).Domains | %{(Get-ADDomainController -Filter * -Server $_ ).hostname}
        $cpu = gwmi win32_processor -ComputerName $DC -Credential $creds
        $disklist = @(gwmi win32_logicaldisk -ComputerName $DC -Credential $creds | ? {$_.drivetype -eq '3'} | select @{N='DriveLetter';E={$_.caption}},description,drivetype,volumename,@{N='Size (GB)';E={[math]::Round(($_.size/1GB),2)}})
            Foreach ($disk in $disklist) {
                New-Object PSCustomObject -Property @{
                    'Domain'=$domain;
                    'Hostname'=$DC;
                    'CPU Model'=$cpu.name
                    'CPU Cores'=$cpu.NumberOfCores
                    'CPU Logical Processors'=$cpu.NumberOfLogicalProcessors
                    'Memory (GB)' = $memory.Capacity/1GB
                    'Drive Letter' = $disk.'DriveLetter'
                    'Volume Name' = $disk.Volumename
                    'Size (GB)' = $disk.'Size (GB)'
            }
        }     
    }
}
```